How do I put a background image at the very top of the window?
I'm a beginner in html/css and I'm manipulating html pages already created by someone else at work.
I can't get my background image to stick to the top of the window.
I've tried a few things with background, background-image, position and color but nothing works.
I've set 'background-color: white;' to try and solve my problem but in this case I've got another problem... The blue of the image used as a background doesn't go all the way to the bottom and I end up with a white background that I don't want.
With white background :

What it looks like with 'background-color: #1f5a86;':

My background-image :

Here are my css lines for the body :


body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0px;
  background-image: url("https://i.sstatic.net/7oF46gQe.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top;
  background-color: white;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Blabla</title>
  <link href="Style_blabla.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
      var d = document;
      if (d.images) {
        if (!d.MM_p) d.MM_p = new Array();
        var i, j = d.MM_p.length,
          a = MM_preloadImages.arguments;
        for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
          if (a[i].indexOf("#") != 0) {
            d.MM_p[j] = new Image;
            d.MM_p[j++].src = a[i];
          }
      }
    }
  </script>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="file:///directory/Style_blabla.css">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="file:///directory/SpryCollapsiblePanel.css">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="SpryAssets/SpryCollapsiblePanel.css">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Liste_deroulante.css" title="Liste_deroulante">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="difusion" style="position: static; width: 220px;"><b>DIFUSION
        </b></div>
  <table class="tableauTitre" style="width: 1128px; height: 138px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tbody id="2" class="Tbleau_onglet">
      <tr>
        <td width="200"><br>
        </td>
        <td width="650"><a href="BlablaTheme.html"><strong></strong></a><strong><a

                name="haut"></a></strong>
          <a href="Blabla_Accueil.html"><img style="border: 0px solid ; width: 810px; height: 120px;" src="Titre_03.png"></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="Deroulant"><a href="#">Accueil  </a>
        <ul class="sous">
          <li><a href="#">Thèmes</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Domaines</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Liste</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="NonDeroulant"><a href="#">Institut  </a> </li>
      <li><a href="#">Catalogues</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" width:="130%">Diffusion</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Glossaire</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>



Thank you for your help.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

MM_preloadImages() instant flashback to early 2000

Also do not load your css from file - instead put them near the html file and use relative addressing like you already do with SpryAssets/SpryCollapsiblePanel.css

@mplungjan Thanks for your advice. I didn't create this html, so I'd be delighted to hear about any possible improvements.

background-position: top left;

Please click [edit], then scroll down and click "edit above snippet and add relevant CSS to the CSS already there. I changed your image to the one you posted to show it

'background-position: top left;' doesn't work. It creates a space on the left edge where you can see the blue background as on the top.

Review your code
If I remove the excess content and focus only on the background image, to prevent stretching the image, I set it to be one screen wide and one screen high. After this adjustment, we still experience margin around the background: this is present on the original photo as a 'transparent' area.



body {
  margin: 0; /* Remove default margin from body. */
  height: 200vh; /* Just for test code. */
  background-image: url("https://i.sstatic.net/7oF46gQe.png"); /* The margin you see now is also present on the original image. Check it yourself by opening the image URL in a new tab. */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top; /* You can place the background image on top like this. */
  background-size: 100%;
  background-color: #205b87; /* Since we don't want to stretch the image, when it ends, we continue with the blue background. I would note that I would initially scale down the background image to include only the white part. */
}



I didn't remove the transparent parts in the review, but if you do that, the criticized 'blue line' will disappear.
In the following example (use smaller photo), however, I have already removed these transparent parts.
Use smaller background photo
I wouldn't include the blue part in the background, making the image unnecessarily larger. Let's crop out only the white strip for the background image. This way, we reduce/optimize the image size. The remaining area can be filled with a color code.



body {
  margin: 0; /* Remove default margin from body. */
  height: 200vh; /* Just for test code. */
  background-image: url("https://i.sstatic.net/JfKr5n32.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top; /* You can place the background image on top like this. */
  background-size: 100%;
  background-color: #205b87;
}



Use SVG instead of photo
Instead of the newly obtained background image, I would use an SVG. The advantage of SVG is that no matter how much you zoom in, it will always provide a sharp image. You need to implement the white part with SVG and then place it at the top of the page.
Use HTML elements
Since the distinctive feature of the background is only the protruding white semicircle, it's intriguing to consider implementing this solely using HTML and CSS. There are two parts:

a header with a white background color. In this, need a extra div formatted as a white circle with a positioned appropriately.
content with a blue background color. (or just set background color to body instead of new div)



* {
  --circle-width: 200px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 200vh;
  background-color: #205b87;
}

.header {
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  height: 100px;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: calc(var(--circle-width) / 7 * -1);
  left: 10%;
  width: var(--circle-width);
  height: calc(var(--circle-width) / 2);
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  
  /* Can write Logo Content to center of circle */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.circle::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: -1; /* Background, behind the .circle. */
}

.header, .circle::before {
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

/* So the content moves towards the div with the .circle class */
.content {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
<div class="header">
  <div class="circle">
    Logo Content Here
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Header Content Here
  </div>
</div>




Thank you, it helps a lot to understand. It works by cropping the image to remove the transparent margins. I'm going to try using HTML elements.

It's strange, with HTML elements I have the same problem of the blue line above the white block. I've looked to see if my logo image has transparent borders, but I don't get the impression that it does, so I don't think that's the problem. I've tried fiddling with the banner properties but nothing works.

@Camille I included an HTML snippet in my response earlier, which produces a similar result to your background. Perhaps if you use that and customize it? ---- If you still struggle, feel free to open a new question where you share your HTML code and ask why the overlay remained on top.

@Camille First, always check for the presence of margin and/or padding. For example, on the <body> element, you almost always need to apply a margin: 0; setting.

I've found the problem, thank you. My header text had a 'margin: 3px auto;'. I replaced it with 'margin: 0px auto;' and the white block now starts from the top.

background-position: top left; 
background-size: cover;

will do it if the image itself does not have transparent edges (which your imgur image did)
I suggest, if you want the white dip, just the image with the dip as background for the navigation and then use background color for the page and banner
Here is the image without the border issues


body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/FZgHb2F.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top left; 
  background-size: cover; /* Ensures the background image covers the entire element */
  background-color: red;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Blabla</title>
  <link href="Style_blabla.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
      var d = document;
      if (d.images) {
        if (!d.MM_p) d.MM_p = new Array();
        var i, j = d.MM_p.length,
          a = MM_preloadImages.arguments;
        for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
          if (a[i].indexOf("#") != 0) {
            d.MM_p[j] = new Image;
            d.MM_p[j++].src = a[i];
          }
      }
    }
  </script>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="file:///directory/Style_blabla.css">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="file:///directory/SpryCollapsiblePanel.css">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="SpryAssets/SpryCollapsiblePanel.css">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Liste_deroulante.css" title="Liste_deroulante">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="difusion" style="position: static; width: 220px;"><b>DIFUSION
        </b></div>
  <table class="tableauTitre" style="width: 1128px; height: 138px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tbody id="2" class="Tbleau_onglet">
      <tr>
        <td width="200"><br>
        </td>
        <td width="650"><a href="BlablaTheme.html"><strong></strong></a><strong><a

                name="haut"></a></strong>
          <a href="Blabla_Accueil.html"><img style="border: 0px solid ; width: 810px; height: 120px;" src="Titre_03.png"></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="Deroulant"><a href="#">Accueil  </a>
        <ul class="sous">
          <li><a href="#">Thèmes</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Domaines</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Liste</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="NonDeroulant"><a href="#">Institut  </a> </li>
      <li><a href="#">Catalogues</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" width:="130%">Diffusion</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Glossaire</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>



